# Windows 7 CHKDSK reports "File record segment 3680 is unreadable" and then blue screens and reboots

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, chkdsk

My computer was working fine yesterday but I booted up this morning and everything was incredibly slow. I have done nothing special for the past few days so I assumed it could be a disk error.

I set it to do a CHKDSK on next reboot and rebooted.

It reports "File record segment 3680 is unreadable" and then blue screens and reboots itself. It goes back into CHKDSK and does the same thing again.

I have now booted into my Ubuntu partition which is working fine. What can I do?

Comment: First check the RAM and the HDD (S.M.A.R.T). You can check the RAM with memtest86+. For the HDD I like to suggest you Hirens Boot CD (memtest is included)

Comment: Find out the HDD manufacturer, try their diagnostics/repair utilities and come back with the results.

Comment: Run Spinrite6 at level 2 to repair the faulty sector(s)...http://www.grc.com/intro.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like there is a physical disk error on your hard drive.

Also sounds like one of the following things is going on:

- The Windows boot process may refuse to continue if boot-time `chkdsk` reports a physical disk error - in all my years I've never had the pleasure of seeing `chkdsk` report such an error so I've never experienced this personally but I would suspect it to be the case.
- The physical error involved may be on a critical system file that Windows needs to run.

The actual error reported by the BSOD may give more clues.

Disk errors can cause sudden slowness in the way you describe.   Honestly I would get important data of that drive now by external means and replace it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. backup your files from ubuntu, reinstall Windows.
2. If 1 fails, you ***MIGHT*** have a faulty hard drive.

For you 1 is more likely than 2, it sometimes happens that you get corrupted segments. If you can't fix it with CHKDSK you must reinstall.

Comment: A faulty sector does not necessarily mean a faulty hard drive. Spinrite6 repairs faulty sectors.

Comment: I didn't say it was a faulty drive, I said it might be a faulty drive.

Comment: What? "If 1 fails, you have a faulty hard drive." I see no "might"

Comment: Well, when you reinstall windows and format the disk it will automatically see the bad sectors and make it so that no data is written to them. However if that fails, it means that there is something else wrong with the drive than just some bad sectors. This means that drive will probably be faulty.

Comment: Then change your answer!